# onClick post request and redirect to another page

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am learning fetch , but i stucked into post request .

I want to make something like , when the user click on button , a post request happens ,  where I get an ID from the request and redirect to fight/ID

My route is set in the **index.js** thats not the problem

**This is my child component**

```
function Fight(props){
     if(props.other === 3) {

        return(
            <div className="row">

                    <button className="btn btn-danger"> Fight</button>
                    <p><i>Your team is ready to fight </i></p>
            </div>
            )
    }
```

Comment: If you speak of "route", are you using a routing library such as `react-router`?

Comment: @Rallen yes i am using react-router

Comment: where is your onClick handler?

Comment: @eramit2010  i don't have it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your Router's `history` prop that wraps your components like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

class App extends Component {
    render () {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In your `Home` component, you have for example a `div` with an `onClick`:
You just do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  clickMe = () => {
      fetch("http://myapi.com/route")
       .then(function(response) {
          console.log("It worked, response is: ", response)
          this.props.history.push({
              pathname: '/nextcomponent'
          }); 
       }).catch(function() {
          console.log("error");
       });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div onClick={this.clickMe}>
        Click Me!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: the problem is that i dont have `class Home extends React.Component`
i have `function Somefucntin()` and in this function i want to use fetch post

Comment: It's the same thing. You put the ``clickMe`` function between the ``function Fight()`` and the ``return( `` and inside your ``return(`` you put the divs with an ``onClick`` prop. You don't have to copy exactly what I posted. See this https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html